# java jbutton change rollover border color

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, rollover

When you roll over a Jbutton there's a greyish border that comes up to show the rollover effect. Is there a simple way to change the color of that border say to red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to tweak the UI Default for what ever look and feel you are using.  This is simple, but finding the correct variable name to adjust normally is the time consuming part.

Comment: "UI Default for what ever look and feel you are using" and for Native OS too (only ButtonModel is), anyway +1